# I would like to store the values in array list after iterating the select options , is it possible in Watir

Tags: watir-webdriver

I am trying to store the values of select list in an array variable

```
a = b.options.each {|option| puts option.attribute_value "value" }
```

Output :

```
IN PROGRESS
UPCOMING
FINAL
POSTPONED
CANCELLED

a.to_i
```

Is it possible to store all values which getting from attribute and store in An array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element collections in Watir include the Enumerable module, which gives a lot of useful methods for iterating. In particular, it includes a `map` method that will perform a block on each element and collect the result in an array.

To store the value of all options, you can simply do:

```
total_list_values = @browser.options.map(&:value)
#=> ["IN PROGRESS", "UPCOMING", "FINAL", "POSTPONED", "CANCELLED"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I coded it like this and its worked, posted if anyone wanted this

```
total_list_values = Array.new

body = @browser.options
     body.options.each do |option|
     total_list_values << option.value
     end
```